# Low impedance vs high impedance sources

Tags: impedance, source

Why is the USB adapter considered low impedance while the solar panel is considered to be high impedance in the below snippet and why do they consider it ideal to be powered from high impedance sources?

[Datasheet BQ24210](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24210.pdf?ts=1658092024445&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

[image]

Comment: USB supplies fixed 5V, the other sources much less so.

Comment: From paragraph 8.3.1 in the data sheet: "_When the input voltage drops to the VBUS-DPM threshold the
internal pass FET reduces the current until there is no further drop in voltage at the input._" That sounds like the essence of what makes it work in solar applications.

Answer (score 1):

A USB output is going to give you a fixed voltage or die trying (5V before USB3.0, more complicated at USB3.0 and later).

A solar panel or TE device will have a V-I characteristic where the voltage drops as more current is drawn from the device -- to the point where the actual power that you're getting from the device is less than what you *could* get at the optimal current draw.  If you have such a source, and you're trying to pull a fixed amount of power from it, **and** that amount of power is more than the source can supply, then your source's output voltage will just be sucked down to zero as the load makes a futile attempt to draw more power.

Hence, input voltage regulation.  Regulating the input voltage doesn't give you actual MPPT*, but it would get you part way there, and it's certainly better than your whole charging system shooting itself in the foot every time a cloud passes over your solar collector.

* maximum power point tracking -- you can get more information than you ever wanted on the subject from a web search.